# Concatenate Remote Database Data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning Laravel and its amazing, so be easy on me please

I have a collection that I get it from a remote database connection

```
$remote_prices_table = DB::connection('remote_mysql')->table('prices')->get();
```

I loop through this table data using `foreach`

```
foreach ($remote_prices_table as $remote_price_record) {
      dd($remote_price_record);
    }
```

Output:

```
{#1860 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Admin\PriceController.php:39
+"product_id": 18101863
+"serial_number": 125
+"product_version": 2
+"product_description": "Kids toy"
+"product_price": 11
+"currency": "USD"
+"store_id": 2
+"aisle": 6
+"shelf": 3
}
```

I need to `CONCAT` and create a new key in this data called `location`
I can do that on the local database level, this way

```
UPDATE prices 
SET 
  `location` = CONCAT(`product_id`, '-', `store_id`, '-', `aisle`, '-', `shelf`)

WHERE `location` IS NULL;
```

But I need to do this in the `controller` where I'm fetching the remote data
So that in the end each `$remote_price_record` Would be like this:

```
{#1860 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Admin\PriceController.php:39
  +"product_id": 18101863
  +"serial_number": 125
  +"product_version": 2
  +"product_description": "Kids toy"
  +"product_price": 11
  +"currency": "USD"
  +"store_id": 2
  +"aisle": 6
  +"shelf": 3
  +"location": 18101863-2-6-3
}
```

How I can achieve this correctly and most important efficiently taking into account that there are thousands of remote records? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly use `transform` on the collection:

```
$remote_prices_table = $db::table('prices')->get();

$remote_prices_table->transform(function ($p) {
    $p->location = "$p->product_id-$p->store_id-$p->aisle-$p->shelf";
    return $p;
});

var_dump($remote_prices_table);
```

Gives:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#20 (2) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#29 (10) {
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(18101863)
      ["serial_number"]=>
      int(125)
      ["product_version"]=>
      int(2)
      ["product_description"]=>
      string(8) "Kids toy"
      ["product_price"]=>
      float(11)
      ["currency"]=>
      string(3) "USD"
      ["store_id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["aisle"]=>
      int(6)
      ["shelf"]=>
      int(3)
      ["location"]=>
      string(14) "18101863-2-6-3"
    }
  }
}
```

Could also possibly use `map` too, in the same way.

Here's a [fiddle link](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/99281ef3a0d2737e1a4f9420e46bd6cd/php/php81/b32bd87d7ec4bf3f614807e679608609/) that I used to create the example.